# DB schema migration in Lift

Tags: scala, migration, schema, lift, database-schema

What are the commonly used DB schema migration tools or libraries in Lift?

Is there anything like [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) in django or rails. Or is this approach considered obsolete in Lift, people have moved on to some new approaches?

Comment: It seems to me that there is no such a thing.

Comment: try this http://code.google.com/p/scala-migrations/. it may help a little.

Answer (score 2):

In our lift app we manage schema migration externally with [DbDeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/).